# Understanding a strange question

Tags: functions, notation, graphing-functions, fractional-part

This question is bizarre to me. I simply don't understand it.

> Plot the graph of the function $x\longmapsto \{x\}$

Any ideas what this means? What is $\{x\}$, and how can you draw a transformation from x to that?

Does this have to do with graph-theory?

Comment: In general $\{ x \}$ is the set having only one element $x$.

Comment: From a mathematics questionnaire online.

Comment: @AlvinL so would that be a straight line, 45 degrees to the x and y axes, as usual?

Comment: Perhaps the [fractional part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part) of $x$ is meant?

Comment: @AlvinL yes, it is specified, Algebra

Comment: If $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part, as suggested, then effectively you're graphing $y=x$ for $x\in (0,1)$ and the function is $1$-periodic.

Comment: @Lewis what makes you think of the fractional part?

Comment: Where did you get the question from? Unless the author spcified the notation, the question can mean literally anything

Comment: fractional fart is the most common meaning of this notation

Comment: @Sgg8 it comes from a an Algebra question-set

Comment: @AlvinL that would become a "saw-tooth function"

Comment: As suggested by others as well

Comment: "Any ideas what this means?" If the book uses notation it doesn't define, then that's the author's problem. Skip and move onto the next question.

Comment: As mentioned by others too, I also feel it is asking to plot a graph for f(x)={x}=x-[x], where [x] is the greatest integer not exceeding x. For example if $x \in [0, \infty)$ then f(x)=x-n for $x \in [n,n+1)$, where $n=0,1,2,3,...$

Answer (score 1):

The most likely meaning is the [fractional part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part#:%7E:text=The%20fractional%20part%20or%20decimal,called%20floor%20of%20x%20or).

Comment: Why the downvotes?